# jQuery selector with tag of length 23+ will fail to find element

Tags: html, jquery, css

jQuery selector cannot seem to find some of my elements.
After spending some time, I have realized that the same code will work with less characters in the id name of the elements.
I have concluded that the maximum character length accepted by the selector is 22.

I have not found any informations on such limits anywhere.

```
<div id="article-skills-analyst-icon"><p>hello first div</p></div>
<div id="article-skills-analyst"><p>hello second div</p></div>
<div id="article-skills-analysti"><p>hello third div</p></div>
```

These won't work:

```
$(`#article-skills-analyst-icon`).bind(`click`, function (e) {
    console.log('triggered');
});
$(`#article-skills-analysti`).bind(`click`, function (e) {
    console.log('triggered');
});
```

This will work

```
$(`#article-skills-analyst`).bind(`click`, function (e) {
    console.log('triggered');
});
```

Note that all elements can be found in the css

```
#article-skills-analyst-icon, #article-skills-analysti, #article-skills-analyst {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? The selector length is not an issue. This is most likely a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6658752/383904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work in the snippet using jQuery. You're probably trying to bind the event before the element exists. You could wrap your binding to wait for the onload event, move your script to the bottom of the page, or defer it.

```js
$(`#article-skills-analyst-icon`).bind(`click`, function (e) {
    console.log('triggered');
});
$(`#article-skills-analysti`).bind(`click`, function (e) {
    console.log('triggered');
});
$(`#article-skills-analyst`).bind(`click`, function (e) {
    console.log('triggered');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article-skills-analyst-icon">
  <p>hello first div</p>
</div>
<div id="article-skills-analyst">
  <p>hello second div</p>
</div>
<div id="article-skills-analysti">
  <p>hello third div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, I am using a class for generating html code and it tries to add the event before it gets initialized. That did not come to my mind, thanks a lot.